# ParserError compiling Smart Contract, what's wrong?

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-test, truffle-compile, atom

I'm getting this error when trying to compile a contract using cmd on windows:

```
Error parsing C:/Users/alexa/Desktop/contracts/contracts/ApprovalContract.sol: ParsedContract.sol:6:37: ParserError: Expected primary expression.
```

> address public constant approver = ;
>
> ```
>             ^ Compilation failed. See above.
> ```
>
> Truffle v5.0.0 (core: 5.0.0)
>
> Node v10.15.0

---

Here's the contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;


contract ApprovalContract {

    address public sender;
    address public receiver;
    address public constant approver = ;

    function deposit(address_receiver) external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        sender = msg.sender;
        receiver = _receiver;
        }

    function viewApprover() external pure returns(address) {
        return(approver);
        }

    function approve() external {
        require(msg.sender == approver);
        receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a deliberate syntax error, followed by "what's wrong with this code?".

Answer (score 1):

This line is invalid

```
address public constant approver = ;
```

Try replacing it with something like this:

```
address public approver;
```

Comment: Thank you abed, I've noticed that I was missing the actual 0x address after the equal sign. Also on:

`function deposit(address_receiver) external payable {`

where it should be 

`function deposit(address _receiver) external payable {`

missing a space there.